# Showing and hiding a row in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to hide and show a row in a table by clicking a button using jquery. I know  the basics of hide and show.

got this to work by using toggle and giving the tr within the table an id.

Comment: yes it's most certainly possible but you need to show us some code/effort.. so that we could help you properly..

Comment: yes it is possible to show and hide a row using jquery. On button click use jquery to select the row you want and then you can use `.show()` and .hide()` methods amongst others

Comment: do I need to give the row an ID for this to work?

Comment: You should give it an `id` or a `class` so you have some sort of identifier to select it with

Comment: If you know the basics of hide and show. Show us what you know...

Comment: yes this is what I thought

Comment: is it the <tr> I need to give an id or class to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you would like to do, but if we consider for instance the following html code:

```
     <table>
  <tr>
    <th>col11</th>
    <th>col12</th>
    <th>col13</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col21</td>
    <td>col22</td>
    <td>col23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col31</td>
    <td>col32</td>
    <td>col33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then you can just write:

```
$("table tr:nth-child(2)").hide();
```

or

```
$("table tr:nth-child(2)").show();
```

where 2 is the 2nd row. You can change it accordingly:

https://jsfiddle.net/gebf2pf2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Some example of what you can do with `hide` and `show` functions of jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide row button click
  $(".hideRowsButton").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").hide();
  });
  
  // Show all rows button click
  $("#showRowsButton").click(function() {
    // Selects every hidden row of the table
    $("#myTable tr:hidden").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="hideRowsButton">Hide</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="hideRowsButton">Hide</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="showRowsButton">Show all rows</button>
```

If you need something specific, fleel free to ask.

Comment: would this work if the user is clicking on a checkbox rather than a button?

Comment: got this to work by using toggle and giving the <tr> within the table an id.